# Iterate through parameters in DbCommand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, interceptor, sqlcommand

I'm trying to intercept and log all `SQL` commands to the database. And I need the parameters and their values as well. But `command.Parameters` doesn't have an `IEnumerable`. I could go for a `for-statement` but kinda feels like a set back.

```
public override void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
{
    _stopwatch.Stop();
    if (interceptionContext.Exception != null)
    {
        _logger.Error(interceptionContext.Exception, "Error executing command: {0}", command.CommandText);

        string param = string.Empty;

        if (command.Parameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var t in command.Parameters)
            {
                param += t....
            }
        }

        Log log = new Log() 
        { 
            Date = DateTime.UtcNow, 
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Error, 
            Message = command.CommandText + "\r\n " + param. 
        };
    }
    else
        _logger.TraceApi("SQL Database", "CommandInterceptor.ScalarExecuted", _stopwatch.Elapsed, "Command: {0}: ", command.CommandText);

    base.ScalarExecuted(command, interceptionContext);
}
```

I need to build a `string` (I know I should use `StringBuilder` in stead of `string` for the `param`, but for the question's sake want to keep it simple) so that I can pass it to the `Message` property of `Log`.

This code is slightly adjusted and taken from [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) blog.

Comment: Why don't you use the in built log functionality of EF 6? It will deliver all SQL Statements and their parameter names/values.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Rand, that is exactly what I'm using, but the link you pasted does it with NLog a third party lib. And the link I pasted doesn't use a third party lib. Both blogs are about intercepting `sql` commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make it a List...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

command.Parameters.Cast<DbParameter>()
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(p => sb.Append(
                                   string.Format("{0} = {1}{2}",
                                      p.ParameterName,
                                      p.Value,
                                      Environment.NewLine)));

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, very neat. Totally overlooked the `Cast()`.